# HTTP response attachment download complete notification

Tags: java, http, netty

In LittleProxy implementation, is there a feature where we can get a notification of the completion of the file download?

Currently I am using below code to save the attachment to the HTTP response message. I am not sure if this `chanBuff.getBytes(...)` a blocking call or non-blocking.

```java
ChannelBuffer chanBuff = response.getContent();
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
chanBuff.getBytes(0, outputStream, chanBuff.readableBytes());
outputStream.close();
```

When I try to process the saved file right after this code, it throws an exception. If I wait till file is completely downloaded and saved on disk, perhaps the problem might get solved automatically.

```
java.io.IOException: Channel not open for writing - cannot extend file to required size
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.AbstractBox.parse(AbstractBox.java:109)
    at com.coremedia.iso.AbstractBoxParser.parseBox(AbstractBoxParser.java:118)
    at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.parse(IsoFile.java:85)
    at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.<init>(IsoFile.java:54)
    at org.media.processor.LibraryImpl.printFileDetails(LibraryImpl.java:529)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChannelBuffer is just encapsulation around byte[].

chanBuff.getBytes(0, outputStream, chanBuff.readableBytes()) will invoke  outputStream.write(byte[], begin, length).

So before you write the content, you should first allocate a corrent length bytes in ChannelBuffer.

Comment: The "chanBuff.getBytes()" function is working fine. I do not think we need to allocate the any memory. I am more interested in to know if there is any way to notify when the write to the outputstream is finished so that I can perform next operations on that saved data.

Comment: Hi Jian, How does it work? If I'm not wrong WriteComplete event is to track the activity on ChannelBuffer. What I am looking for is to monitor the activity (write) on FileOutputStream. If you see above code snippet, getBytes() method writes into the outputStream. I want to check when this write is finished. 

I am not sure if getBytes() function is synchronous (blocking) or nonblocking.